# WSO2 Enterprise integrator preemptive/nonpreemptive authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have question on wso2 EI 6.6.0 and preemptive/non-preemptive authentication. Can I check which incoming calls to wso2 use preemptive and nonpreemtive authentication in Synapse handler? Some systems don't send the HTTP authorization header on the first call and generate error logs in wso2. Is there an attribute in wso2 to determine what kind of authentication it is?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In a non-preemptive scenario, the client sends a request without the `Authorization` header and the server responds to the client with a `WWW_Authenticate` header indicating that the server requires `Authentication` details. So the client will read this header and send another request with the required authentication headers.

To answer your question the only way the server can identify whether the request is a non-preemptive request is to check the existence of the Authorization header. So in your `Authentication Handler` you can check the existence of the `Authorization` header and respond the client accordingly. You can refer [this](https://github.com/yasassri/wso2mi-authorization-handler/blob/main/src/main/java/com/ycr/auth/handlers/AuthorizationHandler.java#L35) Authorization Handler implementation where the non-preemptive scenario is handled.

Comment: So its not possible. because if client use preemptive authentication with missing authorization header(its bug in system for example)  is   same error for preemptive or nonpreemptive(first call) authentication

Comment: Yes, since there is no other unique way to identify this, you can't really differentiate the requests.